# Two stage redirect

Tags: php, url, redirect

I am looking for a two-stage redirect for my website www.listprice.us that will put up an offsite permission notification before redirecting users to a new website. I have a million offsite redirects, need them to go to a single, new page with ultimate destination link in tow and pause there until the user has consented via an agree button to leave my website. I am semi fluent in html, java and php, with no preference except obviously the simpler, and the better explained, the better.

Comment: Like you we also have a preference for simpler and better explained questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a page such as **getpermission.php**.

Through GET bring the Destination URL to that page.

Create a link such as "Yes I Agree" with the link getting pulled from the `GET` or `POST`.

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT:**

`GET: www.mysite.com/getpermission.php?url=www.thesite.com`

```
<a href="<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>"> YES I Agree </a>
```

**Added Source Per Question:**

```
$askconsent = false; //set to true to ask for consent

if ($_GET) { //url has been presented with a GET.
    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'www.domain.com'; //lets make sure url is set. If null set to home.
    //Make sure this has been sanitized before hitting your database if its in one.

    if ($askconsent) { //do we require consent yet?
        echo '<a href="' . $url . '"> Would you like to continue?</a>'; //Present the user with the option to move on.
    } else { // no consent needed.
        header('Location: ' . $url); //go to url from GET
    }
} else { // if we are not presented with a get, we must assume the user got here without wanting or needing to.
    header('Location: www.domain.com'); //Send them home!
}
```

Comment: Just a note: if the users ever have the ability to enter these links into the database I would sanitize and PDO.

Comment: This I understood. Simple is so good. Next step.. I need a replacement page for getpermission.php that will replace this 'I agree' expression for the time being and without interruption go directly to the ultimate destination. Allowing me to at a later date activate this check as needed by merely changing the getpermission.php rather than tens of thousands of web pages.

Comment: A complexity I will surely dream of understanding within which alone my fluency found:

    <?php header('Location: ' . $url); ?>

Answering the second half of my question.

Comment: I find that locating things you have not learned, and forcing your self to learn them is the best way. Write code, it sucks, research, make code better, test, rinse repeat. I have learned everything I know from this method :P I wish you the best of luck.